# How to create multilevel menu using Angular - Bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a multilevel menu for my application using angular and bootstrap. The following is the output

```
Dashboard 
Masters
-- CRMS
---- Customer
---- Customer Types
-- Inventory
---- Item
```

The code I tried is as follows:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav d-flex flex-row flex-grow-1">
  <li class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown placement="bottom left">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="width: 100%" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" style="font-size:14px; color:#000000;">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/#/dashboard">Dashboard </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown" dropdown placement="bottom left">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" dropdownToggle (click)="false"> CRMS </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" *dropdownMenu aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" >
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Customer </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left" *dropdownMenu aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
              <a  class="dropdown-item" href="#/CustomerList">
                                <i class="fa fa-user">
                                </i> Customer
                            </a>
                  </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I know i am doing it all wrong!!!

Can someone help pls? Thanks in advance.